# Including computed `static final` property in an annotation

Tags: java

This works,

```
@JsonRootName(Bay.PLURAL_FORM)
public class Bay {

    public static final String PLURAL_FORM = "bays";
```

This does not (shows error in Eclipse: The value for annotation attribute JsonRootName.value must be a constant expression):

```
@JsonRootName(Bay.PLURAL_FORM)
public class Bay {

    public static final String PLURAL_FORM =
            English.plural(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(
                CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, Bay.class.getSimpleName()));
```

Is there a way to include a computed `static final` in an annotation?

Comment: The value has to be something the _compiler_ can evaluate to a constant. In the second example, the value isn't known until runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. The annotation attribute values must be constant expressions. (Not exactly, the real value accepted depends on the return type of the annotation method. It's all described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1).)

What you can do, however, is give it a key (a `String` value, `enum` value, or `Class` object) that can refer to a value retrieved at runtime. That's how you'll get your dynamic value.

Comment: So in this case I can't do anything because @JsonRootName was not written by me right.

Comment: @jax Right. If you're not the one processing it, there's almost nothing you can do to get the behavior you'd want from dynamic values.